# Move show /Hide password link inside the Password field

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have build a password show/hide functionality and it works perfectly fine. But I am facing a problem. I want to show the show/hide link inside the password field.

Kindly see the screenshot in the link and help me if you know how to do this.

http://screencast.com/t/vH0wc4TSU

```js
      $("#showHide").click(function () {
        if ($(".login-field-password").attr("type") == "password") {
            $(".login-field-password").attr("type", "text");
            $("#showHide").text("Hide");

        } else {
            $(".login-field-password").attr("type", "password");
            $("#showHide").text("Show");
        }
    });
```

```html
    <div class="form-group" >
                    <br />
      <label class="top">Your Account Password</label>
                    <input class="login-field  login-field-password form-control input-lg" name="password-2" id="password-2" type="password" placeholder="Password"  />
                    <a type="button" id="showHide">Show
                    </a>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cwwuL3n4/1/)

Wrap both your input and your `<a>` inside a container, position this container as relative, and the `<a>` as absolute. You can now do whatever you like with the `<a>`.

See the HTML below

```
<div class="form-group">
  <br />
  <label class="top">Your Account Password</label>
  <div class="input-cont">    
    <input class="login-field  login-field-password form-control input-lg" name="password-2" id="password-2" type="password" placeholder="Password" />
    <a type="button" id="showHide">Show
                </a>    
  </div>    
</div>
```

and the CSS

```
.input-cont {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}    
.input-cont a {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 1px;
}
```

See the [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cwwuL3n4/2/) with bootstrap css linked

Answer (score 0):

Make the .form-group position relative
Make #showHide position absolute and use the right and top css parameters to position the #showHide over the input field. Make sure you don't overlap the complete field, that way users will not be able to inset a password